# Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

Tags: php

Estoy intentando sacar un json de una Base de datos, el problema que me da el error que esta en el titulo como puedo solucionarlo?

**Codigo:**

```
 if (isset($_GET["provincia"])) {
if (empty($_GET['ccaa'])) {
  $dbConn->exec("set names utf8");
  $sql="SELECT provincia FROM cp WHERE ccaa = :ccaa";
  $consulta = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
  $consulta->execute($sql);
  $consulta->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  echo json_encode($consulta->fetchAll());
  exit();
}
```

}

Comment: creo es por que en lugar de pasar el valor de `ccaa` a tu consulta le estás volviendo a pasar la consulta como un parámetro, esta debería ser:
``

$sql="SELECT provincia FROM cp WHERE ccaa = :ccaa";
$consulta = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
$consulta->execute(['ccaa' => $_GET['ccaa']]l);
```

Comment: En este me pasa exactamente lo mismo que comento abajo, me salen los corchetes vacios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error ocurre porque en `execute` tienes que pasar un array asociativo con el/los marcador(es) de nombre que hayas usado y el valor por el que se sustituirá ese marcador cuando la API ejecute la consulta, pero tú le estás pasando la consulta como parámetro.

Para simplificar vamos a recuperar el dato con un ternario y luego usamos esa variable para el `if` y para construir el array `$params` que pasaremos a `execute`.

También no necesitas usar `fetchMode` para indicar el fetch style, lo puedes pasar en parámetro a `fetchAll`.

Por ejemplo:

```
 if (isset($_GET["provincia"])) {
    $ccaa=(!empty($_GET['ccaa'])) ? $_GET['ccaa'] : NULL; 
    if ($ccaa){     
      $dbConn->exec("set names utf8");
      $sql="SELECT provincia FROM cp WHERE ccaa = :ccaa";
      $consulta = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
      $params=array(":ccaa"=>$ccaa);
      $consulta->execute($params);
      header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      echo json_encode($consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
      exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: He probado la forma que me ha dicho A.Cedano y al probarlo con la ruta con la que tengo que hacer las consultas y cuando pongo la ccaa me sale corchetes vacios http://localhost/practicaWebServiceBuena/web-service/post.php?provincia&ccaa="andalucia"

Comment: Hola @SergioMartinez. ¿Dónde te salen corchetes vacíos? Al código le faltan algunos controles, como verificar si la consulta trae datos o no para en ese caso enviar un mensaje indicando esa situación. No quise meterme con eso porque se alejaba un poco del problema inicial. Otra cosa extraña en tu código es que verificabas si `$_GET['ccaa']` estaba vacío para lanzar el código...